# While-loop printing variable values one iteration late

Tags: python, loops, printing, while-loop

I'm learning programming using Learn Python The Hard Way. In Exercise 43's Study Drills the author wants us to build a simple combat system for when the hero encounters enemies.

In my combat system, the player and enemy each begin with 100 HP. I set up a list containing 4 prompts the player will be presented with at random. Based on the prompt the player needs to respond with an action. Depending on the scenario and the response, the player loses HP, deals damage to the enemy, or is unaffected. The program prints out both the player's and the enemy's remaining HP whenever they change.

```
health = 100
enemy_health = 100

battle_prompts = [
    "The Gothon raises his rifle, aiming it square in your face.",
    "The Gothon aims, then pauses, realising he's yet to reload his ammo.",
    "The Gothon charges at you at lightspeed, fists clenched tight.",
    "The Gothon runs in your direction, with a menacing grin on his face."
]

while health != 0 and enemy_health != 0:
    battle_prompt = battle_prompts[randint(0,3)]
    print (battle_prompt)
    action = input("> ")
    healthbar = (f"HEALTH: {health} | ENEMY HEALTH: {enemy_health}")
    if battle_prompt == battle_prompts[0] and action == "dodge":
        print ("You dodge the bullet successfully. Nice one!")
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[0] and action != "dodge":
        health -= 25
        print ("You fool! You just got shot!")
        print (healthbar)
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[1] and action == "shoot":
        enemy_health -= 25
        print ("Cool! You just caused some alien bloodshed!")
        print (healthbar)
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[1] and action != "shoot":
        print ("The Gothon reloads his rifle successfully. A wasted opportunity!")
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[2] and action == "block":
        print("You manage to block the Gothon's deadly punches. Way to go!")
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[2] and action != "block":
        health -= 25
        print("What a lamebrain! You just got pounded by an alien!")
        print (healthbar)
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[3] and action == "punch":
        enemy_health -= 25
        print("You give that extraterrestrial invader a beautiful uppercut. Wow!")
        print (healthbar)
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[3] and action != "punch":
        print("The Gothon knocks you over. You're not hurt, but you wasted an opportunity.")
else:
    if health == 0:
        print ("Whoops! Guess you're outta health points! That's all folks!")
        return 'death'
    elif enemy_health == 0:
        print("Good job! You defeated an armed citizen of a galaxy unknown fair and square!")
        return 'escape_pod'
```

I assigned the remaining HP prompt to a variable `healthbar`, but can't seem to get it to work right. If there is a change in HP, it isn't reflected in the prompt printed immediately after; it's only shown the next time there is a change in HP. I guess you could say the prompts are always one loop iteration 'late'.

For example:
If I deal 25 damage the first round the output is
`HEALTH: 100 | ENEMY HEALTH: 100`
In the second round the enemy deals 25 damage. Output:
`HEALTH: 100 | ENEMY HEALTH: 75`
If I dodge an attack the third round the output is:
`HEALTH: 75 | ENEMY HEALTH: 75`

The program calculates the HP values in 'real-time' i.e. if any character's HP hits zero the `else` block of the while-loop is executed, but the prompt still shows they have 25HP remaining.

I tried moving `healthbar` outside of the while-loop, but the prompts showed the HP values to always be at 100. However, when I did away with the `healthbar` variable entirely and replaced each instance of it by pasting the whole prompt, everything is displayed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are formatting `healthbar` (creating the string) with the old health value, modifying the health value, then printing the old health value again.

I would recommend making a "formattable" string template and only formatting when necessary. You could also make a function to print it. I trust that you know how to write a function for this, so here is how to use the format template technique:

```
health = 100
enemy_health = 100

battle_prompts = [
    "The Gothon raises his rifle, aiming it square in your face.",
    "The Gothon aims, then pauses, realising he's yet to reload his ammo.",
    "The Gothon charges at you at lightspeed, fists clenched tight.",
    "The Gothon runs in your direction, with a menacing grin on his face."
]

# Template
healthbar = "HEALTH: {health} | ENEMY HEALTH: {enemy_health}"

while health != 0 and enemy_health != 0:
    battle_prompt = battle_prompts[randint(0,3)]
    print (battle_prompt)
    action = input("> ")
    if battle_prompt == battle_prompts[0] and action == "dodge":
        print ("You dodge the bullet successfully. Nice one!")
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[0] and action != "dodge":
        health -= 25
        print ("You fool! You just got shot!")
        print (healthbar.format(health=health, enemy_health=enemy_health))
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[1] and action == "shoot":
        enemy_health -= 25
        print ("Cool! You just caused some alien bloodshed!")
        print (healthbar.format(health=health, enemy_health=enemy_health))
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[1] and action != "shoot":
        print ("The Gothon reloads his rifle successfully. A wasted opportunity!")
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[2] and action == "block":
        print("You manage to block the Gothon's deadly punches. Way to go!")
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[2] and action != "block":
        health -= 25
        print("What a lamebrain! You just got pounded by an alien!")
        print (healthbar.format(health=health, enemy_health=enemy_health))
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[3] and action == "punch":
        enemy_health -= 25
        print("You give that extraterrestrial invader a beautiful uppercut. Wow!")
        print (healthbar.format(health=health, enemy_health=enemy_health))
    elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[3] and action != "punch":
        print("The Gothon knocks you over. You're not hurt, but you wasted an opportunity.")
else:
    if health == 0:
        print ("Whoops! Guess you're outta health points! That's all folks!")
        return 'death'
    elif enemy_health == 0:
        print("Good job! You defeated an armed citizen of a galaxy unknown fair and square!")
        return 'escape_pod'
```

Answer (score 1):

After each action, you print the **old** `healthbar`.  Then you make your way to the bottom of the loop, input the next action, and only *then* do you update `healthbar` with the results of the previous action.

Fix this by decoupling the printing from the text.  Update and print at the bottom of the loop:

while health != 0 and enemy_health != 0:
    battle_prompt = battle_prompts[randint(0,3)]
    print (battle_prompt)
    action = input("> ")

```
if battle_prompt == battle_prompts[0] and action == "dodge":
    print ("You dodge the bullet successfully. Nice one!")
elif battle_prompt == battle_prompts[0] and action != "dodge":
    health -= 25
    print ("You fool! You just got shot!")
... all other choices ...

healthbar = (f"HEALTH: {health} | ENEMY HEALTH: {enemy_health}")
print (healthbar)
```

Output:

```
The Gothon runs in your direction, with a menacing grin on his face.
> shoot
The Gothon knocks you over. You're not hurt, but you wasted an opportunity.
HEALTH: 100 | ENEMY HEALTH: 100
The Gothon runs in your direction, with a menacing grin on his face.
> punch
You give that extraterrestrial invader a beautiful uppercut. Wow!
HEALTH: 100 | ENEMY HEALTH: 75
The Gothon charges at you at lightspeed, fists clenched tight.
> punch
What a lamebrain! You just got pounded by an alien!
HEALTH: 75 | ENEMY HEALTH: 75
```